# twitter-bootstrap carousel css image resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the carousel example here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel with image of [1200x300](http://placehold.it/1200x300). It looks fine in large screen with width more than 1200. However when I reduce the browser width the image in the carousel decrease and it looks thin.

Is there any trick to have kind of minimum height applied to the image within carousel.

Comment: [min-height - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to achieve what you need.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the inputs. It make sense to let the image to maintain the aspect ratio. However if I need to do some trick to manually set the height when user reduce the screen width media queries should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I think is happening as I don't have any code to look at is that you have responsive bootstrap on which you need to turn off otherwise bootstrap cleverly resizes the objects on the page.

Also I noticed that if you resize the image http://placehold.it/1200x300 then it shrinks though that might not affect it at all

Answer (score 0):

If you set `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` on the `img`, it will retain it's aspect ratio (i.e. remain the correct shape) no matter how narrow you make it.